# finding a line in a file that == x, instead of just having x in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

This is my first question so advice for next time would be appreciated!

So the problem is that I cannot seem to find a line that == x.  I can only find a line with x in it.  If I try:

```
import time
x = input("Enter password here...\n")
start = time.time()
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == x:
            print("Your password is " + line)
            end1 = time.time()
            print("It took " + str(float(end1 - start)) + " seconds to locate your password")
            break
        else:
            print("Passed check")
```

the program will go through the list and finish without printing anything, even if x does in fact equal a word in the list.  But here's where it gets more interesting... if you run the code above I will get an error for everything I type in... EXCEPT if I type in the very last word on the word list as the input(x).  The last word is "albert" and if I type that it will return the result I am looking for.

---

I know I am a terrible explainer but if you put my main code in and try it with the word-list I will attach and then edit the if x in line: to be `if line == x` and try it with words such as password, you will see it doesn't work.  Then try it with albert and *poof* it works.

Is there a way to see if the user input EQUALS the line it is on and is not just in it.   "i.e the word test is in testing, it should only return testing is x = testing and not just test"

Comment: `else:` should probably be on the `for` statement, not `if`. Otherwise you'll get that message for every line that doesn't match the password.

Comment: @DarkstaroneForgot to add the txt file but apparently you guys here don't even need all the equipment to solve issues!

Comment: @Barmar  Thank you so much for you advice and I am implementing it right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read in a line from a text file like:

```
"albert"
```

The file will read in the entire line:

```
"albert\n"
```

Because there are newline chars on every line except the last. So change your code to:

```
import time
x = input("Enter password here...\n")
start = time.time()
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line == x:
            print("Your password is " + line)
            end1 = time.time()
            print("It took " + str(float(end1 - start)) + " seconds to locate your password")
            break
        else:
            print("Passed check")
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're reading lines in a file, you're getting them with line terminators as well (`\n` or `\r\n`) in dependence of the platform. Just right strip them before checking:

```
if line.rstrip() == x:
    # etc.
```

The last one worked because there was no new line after it.